# create objects at specific time with C#

Tags: c#

I want to write a program that create and delete objects of one class at specific time.

for example, one object from a class be created every 4 min and 30 seconds and then be remove at some time after.

How I can do that?

Thanks guys...

Comment: Use a Timer ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it with a backgroundworker:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

worker.DoWork += DoWork();

private void DoWork (object sender, DoWorkerEventArgs e)
{
    bool stop = false;

    while(!stop)
    {
         Thread.Sleep(someTime);
         this.Object = new Object(); // Create your object the way you want.

         stop = e.CancellationPending;
    }
```

}

At this moment I can't test my code. Instead of a Thread.Sleep, you can use a ManualReset;